# How to count specific symbol in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of word that is separated by comma.
So I just want to count each comma and return the total amount in one cell.
I used:

`=ArrayFormula(len(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B11, "[^,]", "")))`

While it will count comma of each cell but it display the total per cell instead of total of all cells. 
So how do I have the total commas count to display in one cell only?
thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty straightforward:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(len(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B11, "[^,]", ""))))
```

[image]